# Who does Stewie confuse Stanley Smith with in S06E06?

Tags: family-guy

[In this dialogue](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0982035/quotes) from Family Guy, Stewie is confronted with Stanley Smith from American Dad. Who does he mean by "Joe" when he says that he looks like him?

Comment: Er, [Joe Swanson](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Joe_Swanson)? Are you being [serious](http://img14.deviantart.net/c8fd/i/2015/194/c/1/joe_swanson_vs_stan_smith_by_hexagondieselbarts-d9133i2.png)? ;)

Comment: Now everything seems so clear :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's talking about Joe Swanson, the neighbor from Family Guy. Stan's facial shape is basically an exaggerated version of Joe's (though the characters are voiced by two different actors). Also, Joe is a police officer, while Stan is an CIA agent.

(This is an inside joke, poking fun at how *American Dad* characters are often accused of being derivative of *Family Guy*).

[image] [image]

Comment: Stan works for the CIA, not FBI